# Maven different jdk version compilation issue

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

This is the pom file of my project:

```
 <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>     
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>2.6</version>
               </plugin>

               <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>**1.2**</source>
                                <target>**1.1**</target>
                                <bootclasspath>
                            ${settings.localRepository}${file.separator}com${file.separator}yyy${file.separator}xxx${file.separator}zzz-RC1${file.separator}xxx-zzz-1.0-RC1.jar
                                </bootclasspath>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                        <execution>
                            <id>java-1.5-compile</id>
                            <phase>**process-test-sources**</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>testCompile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <source>**1.6**</source>
                                <target>**1.6**</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>

                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

While loading the project to run in my native device using  Java 1.2 version it is throwing an error

```
     java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/tvwgfl/class/MyClass[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineVMClass (Native Method)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass (bytecode 125)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    .findClass (bytecode 80)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (bytecode 61)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (bytecode 3)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.ClassLoader.vmLoadClass (bytecode 2)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.Class.forNamex (Native Method)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at java.lang.Class.forName (bytecode 44)[Java] 
        [15:08:36.563][Java]    at com.xxxx.yyyy.reflect.local.impl.CustomClassLoader.run (CustomClassLoader.java, line
```

The source code of the project is made to compile in Java 1.2 version and Test-source in Java 1.6 
version.Also the test source is not loaded to the native device.But even then it is showing the error mentioned.

When done an initial investigation I got a reply,  that Unit Test classes changes were not compiling the Code with 1.1 version but it was compiling with 1.6 as a result the code won’t download on the native device and it will throw class Not supported exception.

is there any way to modify the pom in such a way that it will work in my native device.

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The reported issue is fixed. There is a tag called <plugin> which was added to the pom which resolved the issue.[Plugin dependency of the parent was causing the issue]